# Request method 'POST' not supported in Postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, postman, mapping

I have created this controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/validate")
    public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> validate(@RequestBody @Valid FormulaDTO formulaDto) {
        System.out.println(formulaDto);
        String expression = formulaDto.getFormula();
        service.validate(expression);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new GenericResponse(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), "Expression Validated"),
                HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

The FormulaDTO looks like

```
public class FormulaDTO {

    private String formula;

}
```

I have created a PostRequest from postman whose body contains the formulaText.
The api call from postman looks like

```
https://localhost:8443/validate
```

with body as

```
{
    "formula" :"M00212=curr_month:M00213-curr_month:M00211*100.00"
}
```

I am getting the following as output with 500 Internal Server Error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-05-03",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "details": "uri=/error"
}
```

How can i use PostMapping?

Comment: Please, add all of the code of your controller class. 
Also add the url and how are you calling your api from postman.

Comment: Please look at the updated query

Comment: Your controller has an endpoint called "/validate" but in postman you are using "/validateExpn". Try change it to "/validate"

Comment: sorry my bad. The error is same i.e I am not able to use Post call via postman. Any ideaa why is this happening.

Comment: Please add all of your controller class code. I mean the part where you use de @RestController decorator. Add much code as possible. I'm sure it's a configuration problem

Comment: There is no root level mapping at @RestController . I am pretty sure about the endpoints I have used . Do you think its the Postmans error something else !! I am trying to debug it I am not getting my pointer at the controller. That means the request is not transfeered from postman to the back end !! and I dont know whyyy  !!

Comment: Well it is an uri error (`"details": "uri=/error"`). So please add all of your controller code so I can help you. Thanks. Also, its not a postman error, its a 500 error (an internal server error). Postman has nothing to do with it

Comment: Another thing, try removing the "s" in "https:" from postman. It should be: `http://localhost:8443/validate `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `http` instead of `https` in postman.

Instead of this: `https://localhost:8443/validate`

Use this: `http://localhost:8443/validate`

Comment: There were some entitlement issues, i added few Authentication key and apparently the request was working like a charm ! Thank you for the efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments

> There is no root level mapping at @RestController .

Even if you don't have a root level mapping on controller it seems that spring boot always needs the following annotation on controller level

`@RequestMapping`

Add it and it will be fixed!